Slicing $L$ with a plane can yield a quartic variety?
I'm interested in answering this question:

Given any surface of revolution $L$ embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ with constant positive Gaussian curvature and two fixed cone points, does there exist at least one slice by a plane which yields a quartic variety?

Are there any references I can read that might lead me to the answer? Clearly there are slices of $L$ that yield circular cross sections. So a slice would have to be angled to possibly get a quartic.

The surfaces $L$ of constant positive curvature I know are very non-algebraic when they are no longer spheres.

@TedShifrin Yes, makes sense. I'm trying to resolve a discrepancy that is confusing me. This Q&A: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3286263/460999 shows that using $x^2+y^2=1$ as a generator, or as some call it a "momentum profile," yields a quartic when sliced by the $z=0$ plane. OTOH this Q&A: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4911369/460999 provides $L$ maximized within $[0,1]^3$. I cannot prove that this means that $L$ sliced with some plane ALSO yields a quartic like the other linked question. The surfaces may be different! Any thoughts or recommendations on how to resolve this conundrum?

In any event I think I will make a new question out of that :)

I don’t see what that discussion has to do with a surface of constant Gaussian curvature with two cone points.

@TedShifrin that's because there are four of those surfaces shown as opposed to one. here i simplified things

Nothing to do with constant curvature, I believe.

@TedShifrin Could you elaborate? And to make things focused, I am trying to determine whether $L$ (pertaining to the second link) with maximized volume, and 2 cone points, in $[0,1]^3$ (with constant pos. Gaussian curvature) admits quartic slices by $x,y,z=1/2$ planes. You seem to be saying that this is unlikely...? Is there some argument that says $L$ in this case must be non-algebraic?

Sorry. I had looked only at the first link. Surface of revolution with constant Gaussian curvature are given by rotating a profile curve of the form $(f(u),g(u))$ with $f(u)=A\sin u$ and $g(u)=\int\sqrt{1-A^2\sin^2u},du$ with $|A|<1$. I do not have a proof in mind, but I would be shocked if this elliptic integral could result in an algebraic surface.
